# Copy cells between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need the macro to open wkbk(B) goto row (??) based value entered in wkbk(A) copy certain colmns and paste back to col (j14) in wkbk (A).

```
Sub AutofillData()

Dim wkbkSource As Workbook

Dim strPath As String

Dim myRange As Range

Dim i As Integer

Dim c As Range



     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strPath = "\\"

  Set wkbkSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & Range("A13").Value & ".xls?")


        Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate

         Set myRange = Range("i14:i25")

         For Each c In myRange

            i = c.Value

        wkbkSource.Activate
        Worksheets("Main Data").Select

    Range("D" & i & ":O" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy


    Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
    Range("J14").Select
    Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=False
    Range("J14").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next 

wkbkSource.Close savechanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Error seems to be on this line Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select when i try to change 9 to 10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Ade This "seems to be" would not do. Make sure you know wich line causes the error and what the error (or the error number) is, please.

Comment: @ RB arryYoung and @ Gene Skuratovsky i was getting error "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' Failed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
Sub AutofillData()

Dim wkbkSource As Workbook

Dim strPath As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim wkbkTarget As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strPath = "C:\temp\"

Set wkbkA = ThisWorkbook
Set wkbkB = Workbooks.Open(strPath & Range("A13").Value & ".xlsx")

    Set myRange = wkbkA.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("i14:i25")

    offs = 0
    For Each c In myRange

        i = c.Value

        wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":O" & i).Copy

        wkbkA.Sheets("Data").Range("J14").Offset(offs, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        offs = offs + 1

    Next

wkbkB.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ignotu, i tried you code but was getting this error "Run-time rror '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. This was the highlighted line wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":O" & i).Copy . Thanks

Comment: Make sure to correct the sheet names to the ones in your own workbook. Then try running the code by pressing `F8` to debug line by line. Use the immediate window (`CTRL+G`) to evaluate expression values, by starting the line with `?` then type the expression, finally press `Enter`